# Creating a getJSON object

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, getjson, wait

I've got a successful call going out to a coldfusion database controller using jQuery's getJSON method. The returned information comes back in the format:

```
{
    "COLUMNS": ["PRODUCT_HIERARCHY", "WEBPRODLINE", "POSITION", "FEATURES", "BENEFITS", "LINKS", "VIDEOS", "IMAGE_CUTAWAY", "MARKEDASNEW"],
    "DATA": [
        ["23456689", "ProdName1", "A Feature 1", "A Benefit 1", "url", "vid_url", "img_name", "N"],
        ["234566891", "ProdName2", "A Feature 2", "A Benefit 2", "url", "vid_url", "img_name", "N"]
    ]
}
```

I now want to store the returned information as an object that I can then filter locally instead of making another call to the db. The problem is in the initializeView function. Here's the relevant script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var productsFlag = false;
    var enableLog = true;

    var allProducts = $.getJSON(jsonURL, { method: "getAllProducts", returnformat: "json" }, function(data) {
        productsFlag = true;
    });

    waitOnJson();

    function waitOnJson() {
        //this shows up in the log
        logThis('areProductsReady?');
        if (productsFlag) {
            //this shows up in the log
            logThis('productsFlags ready');
            initializeProductView();
        } else {
            //this shows up in the log
            logThis('productsFlags not ready');
            t = setTimeout(waitOnJson, 100);
        }
    }

    function initializeProductView() {
        //this shows up in the log
        logThis('initializeProductView');
        //this displays [object Object]
        alert(allProducts);
        //this displays undefined
        alert(allProducts.DATA);
        $.each(allProducts.DATA, function(i, item) {
            //this doesn't show up in the log
            logThis(item[1]);
        });
    }

    //as you can tell, this writes out to a debug console on the page
    function logThis(eventString) {
        if (enableLog === true) {
            $('<p/>').append(eventString).appendTo("#log");
        }
    }

});
```

I'm sure that the problem is in my lack of understanding about what getJSON is returning but I've either had too much caffeine or not enough and I'm not seeing it. HELP!

Also, any thoughts on my blocking wait step? I want to be able to use the data in several different functions but I also need to wait for it to load before initializing the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you shouldn't have to wait on the json response like you are. The function in your getJSON method call only returns when a response is received. When it does, it returns the results of your JSON call as the first argument of the method call. So you can just do something like this (I stripped a lot of your stuff out for simplicity sake):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON(jsonURL,
    {
        method: "getAllProducts",
        returnformat: "json"
    }, function(allProducts) {  //This function only executes when the response is received.

        //You access your products array here and do whatever you need with them
        alert(allProducts != null);

    });


});
```

Hopefully that clears things up somewhat.

**EDIT:** After reading your comment, if the alerts in your initializeProductView method are what you're confused about, it's probably because the getJSON method doesn't return the result of the JSON AJAX request, it returns an [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR). That's why the .DATA attribute is undefined. If you did something to the effect of this, it would potentially work (assuming your returned JSON has a .DATA member):

```
var allProducts = null;

$.getJSON(jsonURL,
    {
        method: "getAllProducts",
        returnformat: "json"
    },
    function(data) {
        productsFlag = true;
        allProducts = data;
    }
);
```

Sorry about my misunderstanding earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm aware of how the callback function works in getJSON. However, I will need to initialize the view again later (for example, if someone resets product filters) so I'm initializing it outside of the callback function. It works as I have posted it above except that I'm either not assigning the data correctly or not referencing it properly in the initializeView function.

Comment: I put some additional information above after reading your comment since code explained it a bit easier. Sorry about that.

Comment: LOL! I was just about to answer my own question as that's (your edit) EXACTLY what I ended up doing. I was just being too damn stubborn and convinced that my original code would work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do all the stuff currently in your wait step in an anonymous callback function submitted in the `.getJSON()`? It's much cleaner, and you don't have to keep doing the `setTimeout` gig.

As to what's happening with `initializeProductView()`, it's obviously getting called. Please post the code for it. You definitely need to be doing something with the `data` parm in the callback. Right now it's not being used.

For reference, and a closer look, heres the `getJSON` page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

---

EDIT: You're not doing anything with the JSON response. In the callback you should be doing something with the data parm. How are you accessing it in `initializeProductView()`?

---

EDIT 2: You're anonymous function called by `ready` is not properly closed.

---

EDIT 3: Taking a closer look, you've defined `waitOnJson()`, `initializeProductView()` and `logThis()` as methods of an anonymous function. When a call is made to the functions, you're calling them as if they're top level functions. Your anonymous function should really only do work, not define functions to be called.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason for moving it out of the getJSON callback function and is that I want to be able to re-initialize the data again later without making another getJSON call. The idea being a reduction of the number of calls to the database. I just want to get the product list once, store that data in a local object and process it as needed. As for the initializeProductView() function, you're looking at the whole thing so far. Nothing is being kicked out to the log.

Comment: @Chris, See my edit. Also, your post says "productsFlags ready" *is* showing up in the log. Is it showing?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The solution was in the edit that Bit Destroyer posted. I was assuming that the getJSON call was producing an object. I ended up needing to assign the object inside of the callback function.